# How can I get a graphical representation of the traffic going through my switch

Tags: networking, switch, snmp

I have a small home network with 4 PCs, several tablets and a number of appliances.
These all route to the WAN router through a Netgear Managed Switch (GS724Tv4).

I have noticed that the network slows down a couple of times an hour; noticeable as video stream stutter.

I would like to see a graph of network traffic over the network and into the WAN over time so I can trace any resource hungry devices.

I see my switch has a Port Monitoring function.  However, the information it gives me is text/number based and is a snapshot in time.

I have spent some time researching this, looking at SNMP and the products that use that but I am not convinced I am pursuing the correct course.

What should I be doing to see the traffic on my network, broken down by Port and preferably device IP or physical Switch socket.

Comment: So your internet connection first goes through a modem of some type, then the switch, then the router? If the router has better graphing I'd try making it the first "stop" in front of the switch if possible. An OpenWRT/dd-wrt/Tomato based router/swtich might be much more informative, mine has tons of graphs & settings I'll never need, and can log almost everything... if your switch at least can save CSV logs you could graph them in a spreadsheet

Comment: The router is the device that connects to the WAN.  It is "effectively" a modem with a hub built in.  The router is supplied by my ISP (SKY in the UK).  It has no logging and it can't be easily replaced with a different, better router.
So the path is WAN-Router-Switch-local network(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That switch seems to support RMON which is pretty much what you need - using an appropriate monitoring tool you can check port loads, error counters etc over time.

RMON doesn't provide a traffic breakdown into streams though, that would require sFlow or similar.

Comment: After trying a few clients I went with Paessler PRTG because of its ease of use and because it works on Windows 7.